# Why is there only one stateful session bean?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean

I tried following example for a stateful session bean http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/example-of-statelfulbean.shtml, but when I use two browsers I only get the same session bean.
I thought there is a session bean for each connection/client. What is wrong?

I use the JBoss 5.0.1 AS for testing and deploying.
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Are you using to different browsers (Firefox/Chrome) or two different browser windows (Two Firefox windows)?

Comment: I used different browsers. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I got the session bean in the servlet once, but I have to get it for each session and store it in the session data.